# How to proof that the median of a lognormal distributions equals $\exp(\mu)$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

If $V$ is lognormal distribution, how can you prove that his median equals $\exp(\mu)$? With $\mu$ the mean of the normal distibuted $\ln(V)$

Answer (score 5):

The random variable $V$ is log-normally distributed if and only if $\ln V$ is a normal random variable.

Since the logarithm is a monotonous function, the median of $\ln V$ is the logarithm of the median of $V$. Equivalently, the median of $V$ is the exponential of the median of $\ln V$. (1)

The variable $\ln V$ has a normal distribution, which is symmetric. Therefore its median equals its mean $\mu$.  (2)

From (1) and (2), the median of $V$ is $\exp(\mu)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** A real number $m$ is a median of the distribution of a random variable $X$ iff it satisfies the inequalities $P(X \ge m) \ge \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(X \le m) \ge \frac{1}{2}$. You only need to prove that $\exp(\mu)$ satisfies this property.